# How to prove the uniqueness criteria of the inner product defined on $L^2$ space

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, inner-products

While trying to prove the uniqueness property ($⟨x,x⟩=0$ iff $x=0$), I understand that I would arrive at a point like this:
$$⟨f,f⟩= \int |f(x)|^2 dx=0.$$
Following which I have to somehow prove that $f$ is identically zero.

However, from what I know, (and currently my understanding of lebesgue intergration is loose and informal, sorry) since Lebesgue integrable functions can be discontinuous, it's not possible to conclude that
$\int|f(x)|^2 dx$ implies $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [a, b].$

Is there something I'm missing/getting wrong? How would we go about proving the uniqueness criteria?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not true in $\mathcal{L}^2$, the set of square-integrable functions, since as you say we may have discontinuities, for example.  It's only true in $L^2$, which is what we get when we quotient by the set of $f$ with $||f||_2 = 0$.  In $L^2$ this is true essentially by definition. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Lp_spaces_and_Lebesgue_integrals) for the definitions of $\mathcal{L}^2$ and $L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ is a measured space and $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a $\mathcal{A}$-measurable application satisfying
$$\int |f|d\mu = 0,$$
then $f=0$ almost everywhere. Since in $L^2$, two functions which are equals almost everywhere are equals, you have $f=0$.